# XSLT static key declaration using sequence constructor instead of @use?

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

XSLT2.0 seems to allow declaring key inline, inside the `<key>` element.
All the examples I have seen declare an intermediate XML fragment and match on that, using `@use`. I think that is wasteful.
Can you please provide an example of a XSLT 2.0 key declaration using sequence constructor inside the key element rather than `@use`?

Comment: Why do you mention "regexp" in your question? `use` is an attribute with an XPath expression, but not with a regular expression.

Comment: Sorry what are you referring to?

Comment: The title of your post ends with "instead of @use regexp?" Why "regexp"?

Comment: done. Now give me your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the value that you want to index is a very simple function of the objects being indexed, so the @use attribute works perfectly well. You can use a contained sequence constructor for more complex cases if you need to, but I've very rarely seen it needed. For example you might want to index sections by their section number like this:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="section">
  <xsl:number level="multi" count="section" format="1.1.1"/>
</xsl:key>
```

I don't know what makes you think that using the @use attribute is "wasteful".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have used that feature so far and I can't think of a good sample for an obvious use case but let's assume `foo` elements have some `value` child elements and we want to sort the `value` elements and only key on the first or last few in sort order so we could use e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="by-first-three-values" match="foo">
  <xsl:for-each select="value/xs:decimal(.)">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() lt 4">
      <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:key>
```

Of course you could avoid that use by writing a function that sorts with `perform-sort` and then call that function in `use="mf:sort(value)[position() lt 4]"` but I guess there is at least the flexibility to do it inline of the `xsl:key`.

Answer (score 0):

What I am after is even more simple, something similar to:

```
<xsl:key name="AcronymKey" match="a:acronymItem" use="a:acronym"/>

<xsl:template name="AcronymnStandsFor">
    <xsl:param name="acronym"/>
    <!-- change context to current document so the key will work -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('AcronymKey',$acronym)/a:standsFor"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<a:acronymList>
    <a:acronymItem>
        <a:acronym>Ant</a:acronym>
        <a:standsFor>Another Neat Tool</a:standsFor>
    </a:acronymItem>

  </a:acronymList>
```

But where the actual key is inside the key element. Is that possible, given the syntax?

Comment: This is not an answer, is it? Please delete this and edit your question instead. Make sure to include your XML input as well, so that we understand the context. -- P.S. In XSLT 2.0 it is **not** necessary to switch context before using a key.

Comment: I'd though about it before adding comment, but it is the answer - it works. It's not exactly what I was looking for but it is the closest to what I was after. Unless someone can come up with a syntax where the mapping is inside the key element, I'll use the above...

Comment: I believe that `<xsl:key name="AcronymKey" match="a:acronymItem"><xsl:sequence select="a:acronym"/></xsl:key>` would be the exact equivalent of what you have now. With no advantage whatsoever over what you have now.

Comment: @michael.hor257k initially, I'd hoped I could literally type the content of the key inside the key element. This would have been a nice isolation and encapsulation,  as it stands, I still need a separate a:acronymList bock, just to hold the key-value pairs and then a separate block to map them. It's very verbose so in my my actual production code I ended up skipping the key abstraction altogether...

Comment: It's difficult to understand what exactly you are after. You certainly *can* place literal values inside the key - provided that you know them when writing the stylesheet. -- Other than that, XSLT is naturally verbose - better get used to it. And **key** is not an "abstraction" but an efficient way to lookup data - you should not give up on it, if that's what you need to do.